How to handle accented letter in Pyspark
I have a pyspark dataframe in which I need to add "translate" for a column.
I have the below code
df1 = df.withColumn("Description", F.split(F.trim(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.lower(F.col("Short_Description")), \
        r"[/\[/\]/\{}!-]", ' '), ' +', ' ')), ' '))\
        
df2 = df1.withColumn("Description", F.translate('Description', 'ãäöüẞáäčďéěíĺľňóôŕšťúůýžÄÖÜẞÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔŔŠŤÚŮÝŽ',
                                       'aaousaacdeeillnoorstuuyzAOUSAACDEEILLNOORSTUUYZ'))
                                       
df3 = df2.withColumn('Description', F.explode(F.col('Description')))

I'm getting datatype mismatch error: argument 1 requires string type, 'Description' is of array<string> type
I need to handle the accented letters in Description column.
Please let me know how to solve this

why not just apply F.translate() before F.split()

Try using spark higher order functions transform to iterate through array and replace.
Example:
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df= spark.createDataFrame([(1,['123a','2431abc'])],['id','description'])

df.withColumn("description",expr("""transform(description,x -> translate(x,'abc',''))""")).display()

#result:
#+---+-----------+
#| id|description|
#+---+-----------+
#|  1|[123, 2431]|
#+---+-----------+

